# Vue.JS prints empty values from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, vue.js

I'm writing this code where a Vue.JS module calls a PHP file that fetches data from an external server and returns a JSON response. I had written a loop for getting a particular field from JSON and print them in a conversation format. But it displays only **empty message bubbles with no text** (The number of message bubbles is correct but no text inside it).

Here's my code:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#chatview",
  data: {
    data:[],
    txtInput: '',
    mid:0

  },

    methods:

    {

    GetBubbleType: function (name){

    if(name === "Support")
            return "yours messages";
    else
            return "mine messages";
    },

    },

    mounted(){
                        axios.post(
  './ConversationGetter.php',
  {
    function2call: 'getRecord',
    id: 1,
  }
)
.then(response =>  {this.data=response.data.data;
console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {});

},
    template: `
  <div style ="font-family:Open Sans;font-size:16px"> 
    <div v-for="message in data">
  <div class="fade-in">
        <div v-bind:class="GetBubbleType(data.name)">
        <div class="message last">
        <p>{{data.message}}</p>
        </div>

        </div></div></div>  `
})
```

The response returned from PHP:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Modified_Time": "2019-12-13T16:08:36+05:30",
      "$currency_symbol": "$",
      "Message": "Hey!",
      "Created_Time": "2019-12-13T16:08:36+05:30",
      "Name": "Me",
    },
    {

      "Modified_Time": "2019-12-13T16:08:27+05:30",
      "$currency_symbol": "$",
      "Message": "Yo!",
      "Created_Time": "2019-12-13T16:08:27+05:30",
      "Name": "Me",
    },

  ],
}
```

Comment: you refer to `data.name` but it should be `data.Name` - case is significant in javascript - you also have `"message in data"` then use `data.name` ... so it actually should be `GetBubbleType(message.Name)`

Comment: The result is still the same after changing the case.

Comment: see the other mistake you made ... use message not data, since message is each value of data

Comment: Side note, why is your conversation getter method a POST request?

Comment: Also, is the JSON response you posted in the second block of code `response.data.data`? Or is that `response.data`?

Comment: You should call the message since you are looping through the data 
it should be `{{message.message}}` not `{{data.message}}` in <p> tag

Comment: @MikeK It is response.data.data There is another data  tag surrounding the entire data thing.

Comment: @MikeK It is a POST request because I needed to pass some arguments to the function on PHP

Comment: You could do that with a GET request and some query params, such as `axios.get(url, { param: 'someData' })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the message since you are looping through the data prop it should be `{{message.Message}}` not `{{data.message}}` inside the paragraph tag

When you loop through data prop each loop object contains message meta data

```
{

      "Modified_Time": "2019-12-13T16:08:27+05:30",
      "$currency_symbol": "$",
      "Message": "Yo!",
      "Created_Time": "2019-12-13T16:08:27+05:30",
      "Name": "Me",
    },
```

You should be able to access each `object property` like this `{{message.Message}}` inside the v-for loop